# where can i find all the xml namespaces URIs in android?

Tags: android, namespaces

Since there are different namespaces like tools, android and so on:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Are there some page on the documentation or folder in the sdk where I can see the xml namespaces URIs that exist?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for **[Recource Types](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html)** + **[Manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html?hl=en)**?

Comment: Basically the xmlns URIs.